# Jquery just does not want to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I suck at Jquery and Javascript.

I've been trying to make this work:

```
debugger;

(function () {
    $('form input').keyup(function () {

        var url = [false, false, false, false, false];
        var plus = 0;
        $('form input').each(function () {
            plus = plus + 1;
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                url[plus] = true;
            }
        });

        $("#demo").text(url);
    });
})()
```

But jquery won't even set the #demo text at all, nothing is happening whatsoever.

html:

```
<div class="inner cover">
     <h1 class="cover-heading">Create.</h1>

    <p class="lead">
        <form action="./index.php?p=create" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url" type="text" id="url" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url2" type="text" id="url2" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url3" type="text" id="url3" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url4" type="text" id="url4" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url5" type="text" id="url5" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="submit_url" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Go!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

What are all of the things I've totally done all wrong?

**(I've been testing this in JSfiddle)**

Thanks in advance.
-G

Comment: Please provide any more info, like browser console log

Comment: Did you try debugging in Chrome (or your favourite browser) to see if the function is actually executed when you expect it to? And if it is, that it behaves as you expect it to?

Comment: It was not a problem with jQuery, you could have tested by placing $("#demo").text("yo"); outside the $(...).keyup(function() {});

Comment: @Kalyan I've never really debugged Jquery in browser before so I'm not really sure how but I updated my post. Console or debugger isn't really showing me anything... I think? Nothing that seems to relate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form > input')
```

should be

```
$('form input')
```

Becase `>` means "[direct child](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)" and you have a `div` between `form` and `input`

Comment: I've tried this:

`(function () {
    $('form input').keyup(function () {

        var url = [false, false, false, false, false];
        var plus = 0;
        $('form > input').each(function () {
            plus = plus + 1;
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                url[plus] = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        $("#demo").text(url);
    });
})()`

But it's still not outputting anything

Comment: there's another `form > input` inside. Please note that I've not seen the logic inside the function. :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry I did remove that before but it didn't make a difference, still no output.

Answer (score 0):

`$('form > input')` requires inputs to be direct descendants of "form". yours are wrapped in DIVs. the correct selector is `$('form input')`

```js
(function () {
  $('form input').keyup(function () {

    var url = [false, false, false, false, false];
    var plus = 0;
    $('form > input').each(function () {
        plus = plus + 1;
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            url[plus] = true;
        }
    });

    $("#demo").text("yo");
  });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Create.</h1>

    <p class="lead">
        <form action="./index.php?p=create" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url" type="text" id="url" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url2" type="text" id="url2" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url3" type="text" id="url3" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url4" type="text" id="url4" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url5" type="text" id="url5" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="submit_url" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Go!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

**AS PER REQUEST IN COMMENT**: again, selector is not "form > input", is "form input". Also, what's "empty" in your IF? this works:

```js
(function () { 
  
  var url = [false, false, false, false, false];
  var plus = 0;
  
  $('form input').keyup(function () {
    
    $('form input').each(function () {
      plus++;
      
      if ($(this).val() == '')
        url[plus] = true;
    });
    
    // WHAT'S EMPTY??
    
    /*
    if (empty) {  
      $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
      $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    */
    
    $("#demo").text(url);
  });
  
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Create.</h1>

    <p class="lead">
        <form action="./index.php?p=create" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url" type="text" id="url" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url2" type="text" id="url2" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url3" type="text" id="url3" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url4" type="text" id="url4" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url5" type="text" id="url5" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="submit_url" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Go!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this:

`(function () {
    $('form input').keyup(function () {

        var url = [false, false, false, false, false];
        var plus = 0;
        $('form > input').each(function () {
            plus = plus + 1;
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                url[plus] = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        $("#demo").text(url);
    });
})()`

But it's still not outputting anything

Comment: @Haxo201   I edited my answer adding a new snippet with the code you provided in your comment. that should work, but I had to comment-out the portion related to "#register" which is not in your html code

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't mean to leave that in there, that part of the code is not relevant right now and I removed it completely. But I get no output in <p id="demo"> still

Comment: @Haxo201, the above snippet is working. Is it possible that you're not including the jquery library?

Comment: I'd think not since I'm testing in JSfiddle with Jquery 1.5 onLoad :S

Comment: @Haxo201 can you post a link to your fiddle?

Comment: @Haxo201 http://jsfiddle.net/22qtkqLz/23/  jQuery 1.5 won't work. works with jQuery 1.8  :)

Comment: Yes, I've had that pointed out to me by another person on here too now, haha. I don't even know how I've been on an ancient version tbh. :( Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) select all input who have parent a `form` tag, but all your input have parent a `div` tag.

Try this:

```
$('form input')
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('form > input')` selects direct input descendants of form, like this:

```
<form>
  <input />
</form>
```

but since you have this structure:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input />
  </div>
</form>
```

you need to use `$('form > div > input')`, or, more loosely, just `$('form  input')` (without the `>` character).

---

See it here:

```js
(function () {
    $('form input').keyup(function () {

        var url = [false, false, false, false, false];
        var plus = 0;
        $('form input').each(function () {
            plus = plus + 1;
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                url[plus] = true;
            }
        });

        if (plus == 0) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        $("#demo").text(url);
    });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner cover">
     <h1 class="cover-heading">Create.</h1>

    <p class="lead">
        <form action="./index.php?p=create" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url" type="text" id="url" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url2" type="text" id="url2" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url3" type="text" id="url3" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url4" type="text" id="url4" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url5" type="text" id="url5" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="submit_url" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Go!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated my post. Still no output when I edit the fields.

Comment: Modified my code, you have `if(empty)` where `empty` was not defined, what is it supposed to represent? I replaced it with `plus == 0`.

Comment: Yeah sorry that's not relevant code right now, I removed it.

Comment: So is it solved? I gave you the working code, are you still having problems?

Comment: Well I'm still not getting any output to <p id="demo"> and I don't know why

Comment: But it's there in my example, you just might need to scroll a bit, or go full screen.

Comment: Nothing's happening for me... Here's a JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/22qtkqLz/20/

Comment: You were using an ancient version of jQ - it works fine with the latest: http://jsfiddle.net/22qtkqLz/21/

Comment: Oh my GOD I didn't know it was so old... How'd that even happen. :( Thank you so much! Will continue trying to make this do what I want now. Thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah, it's very old, it probably uses a different syntax for keyup or something. Try to stay at 2.0+. You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so through the help of several people on here (credit to all of you, thanks for your help!) I finally reached a solution that works perfectly. :)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    (function () {
        $('form input').keyup(function () {

            var url = [false, false, false, false, false];
            var plus = -1;
            var next;
            $('form input').each(function () {
                plus = plus + 1;
                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                    url[plus] = true;
                    next = plus + 1;
                    $("#url"+next).show();
                } else {
                    url[plus] = false;
                    next = plus + 1;
                    $("#url"+next).val("");
                    $("#url"+next).hide();
                }
            });
        });
    })()
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="inner cover">
    <h1 class="cover-heading">Create.</h1>
    <p class="lead">
        <form action="./index.php?p=create" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url0" type="text" id="url0" class="form-control" placeholder="URL" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url1" type="text" id="url1" style="display:none" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url2" type="text" id="url2" style="display:none" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url3" type="text" id="url3" style="display:none" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="url4" type="text" id="url4" style="display:none" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="submit_url" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Go!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </p>
</div>
```